# How to avoid intermittent Errno::ETXTBSY exceptions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

During part of a request in a Rails application, I copy a directory from one place to another, think of it like a working area. Sometimes this copy operation results in "Errno::ETXTBSY" exceptions being thrown. I can't seem to pin down the case that causes it, any tips to detect the case or avoid it altogether?

I've made sure the destination directory is uniquely named, so it shouldn't be a case of 2 processes attempting to write to the same place. Beyond that I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ETXTBSY means that you're trying to open for writing a file which is currently being executed as a program, or that you're trying to execute a file which is currently open for writing. Since you say you're copying files, not executing them it seems likely it's the former, not the later.

You say you're targeting a unique new destination, but my guess is that's not entirely true and you're actually targeting an existing directory and one of the files you're attempting to overwrite is currently open as an executable text segment of a running process.

You haven't posted any code, so it's hard to comment specifically.  I suggest you add enough logging so you know exactly what file(s) are being processed and specifically, the source and destination path that throws the exception.  Then you could use [`lsof`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) to see what process may have that file open.

One way to avoid the problem if you are overwriting a currently open executable, is to first [`unlink`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-unlink) the target file.  The running process will still have the old inode mapped and proceed merrily using the deleted file, but your open for write will then create a new file which won't conflict.

Comment: None of the files are "executables" does that change anything? I generate a unique directory name based on time down to the millisecond and some random information, there isn't enough load (or concurrent users) to make 2 identical names be generated with any likelihood. I'll try the unlink tip, that sounds pretty good! Accepting your answer as it is very through, thank you!

Comment: Since you claim the destination is empty and unique, I wonder if maybe it's your source file(s) which are open for execute elsewhere; if you've opened them in both read and write mode you can get this exception even though you have no intent of actually writting to them.

Comment: I encountered a similar error while trying to build capybara-webkit from github:master via bundle install. I solved it by completely removing the bin/webkit-server folder withing the gem directory (in my case a la rvm gemset) and running bundle install again.

Comment: I followed @ballPointPenguin's advice, but note that `bin/webkit_server` has an underscore, not a dash, and it's an executable, not a folder. Remove it, then run bundle (which will now succeed), and it'll reappear.